# Unable to search properly on Stack Exchange sites using the browser in Android

Tags: support, mobile-web, android, browsers

On Stack Exchange sites, when I select the primary search input box in the upper right corner and type in my search term, there is no 'go' button available. Instead there is a 'next' button which takes me to the input fields for interesting tags and then to ignored tags.  Since the browser doesn't recognize it as its own form it won't let me issue a search from that interface and because there is no UI element to actually submit a search, there's no way for me to execute my searches.

My tests were conducted using the stock UI on the Samsung Vibrant (Galaxy S) running Android 2.1 and the Samsung TouchWiz UI.

Comment: A similar case of mobile users who cannot use search for linked section ♪ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51057/no-search-button-accessibility-problem for linking

Comment: Android 2.1 is [significantly less than 1% of all active devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/4448), so this is effectively a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me on an HTC Incredible by entering the search term and hitting the Enter button (bottom right of the std keyboard).

Comment: There's no enter button on my swype input keyboard when I'm in that field.