# I need a search button

Tags: feature-request, support

I know this is a duplicate post, but consider it a mild form of civilian disobedience.
I mainly use my Android phone to surf the web, including this forum, and since it's a feature to replace the enter/carriage return/whatever it is button with a next button as soon as there are more than one text input field, and it's a feature of Stack Overflow to not have a search button next to the search field, I can't search Stack Overflow with my phone.

Would it really break the design that much to put a button next to the search text field?

Here's the duplicate question: [No Search button - accessibility problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51057/no-search-button-accessibility-problem).

Comment: So I guess the down vote is either the fact that this post is a duplicate, or that someone didn't share my opinion on the subject. If one reads the duplicate question one finds that one of the answers are of the kind "it's not my fault so why should I bother". I would like to know if that is general consensus or if not, why it can't be implemented?

Comment: I think the button should be implemented for those clients that are giving trouble otherwise, no matter whose fault it is. Still, this could be an answer to that other question

Comment: Point taken. I'm new here, and I thought that since the duplicate was active ten months ago, and since I didn't have an "answer", the correct thing to do was to ask again... Sorry for that.

Comment: I search via my Android phone all the time. What's the issue?

Comment: I can enter text in the search field, but then my enter button on the keyboard has magically changed into a next button to help me enter data into other parts of the form. The other text input fields on the page are not part if the search form, so I can't submit my search string and hence the search procedure does not commence... This might be a Samsung feature though...

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an issue specific to the Galaxy with Android 2.1; according to [How to use the Search box on these Stack Exchange sites with the Galaxy S?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/how-to-use-the-search-box-on-these-stack-exchange-sites-with-the-galaxy-s) this was fixed in the update to Froyo.