# Why is there no "Search" button beside the search field?

Tags: discussion, search, design

Why isn't there a Search button? It's actually disconcerting to simply hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after I type in my search terms.  It's like, "I'm hoping this will search, but I'm really not sure."

Comment: There is no search button to identify with the programmers out there who really don't use the mouse unless its **absolutely necessary**. :)

Comment: Do you use the Go button in Internet Explorer?

Comment: two scenarios where it would be good to have a button: 1)your enter key is broken or missing, 2)someone planted a bomb that is triggered with the enter key

Comment: Maybe that's what stops people from searching *before* [asking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51057/148672) a [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97235/i-need-a-search-button). As a side note the UX people [seem to think](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/126/do-you-need-a-search-button-with-a-search-box) yeah you probably should have a search button in this case

Comment: Six: Is that program of some sort??

Comment: At least a small "Go" button would be useful. I'm not able to make any searcheds on SO from my Opera mobile browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter some dummy search in the box, you'll be presented with the [search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=foo&submit=search) page. There you *will* find a search button at your disposal.

[image]

I don't feel that this is much of an issue really. It is a UI/UX design decision that was made because pressing enter after entering a search query actually **is** intuitive IMO. I have a feeling that people would agree with me on that.

Comment: This seems only minimally useful. The only __convenient__ way to reach the search results page is to submit a search from the button-less field. If you're going to have to use the no-button field at any point, you might as well just do your real search directly from there.

Comment: @Lix you might want to check out [Do you need a search button with a search box?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/126/2234) it seems the UX community doesn't agree. You might be experiencing a [Dunning–Kruger effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) where due to expert ability to intuit a UI you overestimate the ability of others.